# What ASP.NET MVC project files should I not add to Subversion

Tags: asp.net, svn

this is likely a naive question, but I want to do this right the first time.

I have a MVC solution which has the following:

```
 Data project - C#
 Services project - C#
 MVC Web Project -  ASP.NET MVC
 Test Project
```

Currently, I am using the MVC2 source as a means to debug my own code.  I do not plan on checking that in, but I realize once I go back to the MVC2 DLL, my solution will change.

I'm pretty sure I just shouldn't check in stuff that changes with each build:  the bin folder on the Web project, for example.

Is there a list of what not to commit to source control? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exclude the bin folder.  Also be on the look out for .user or .suo files.  Those file store your own settings and will change from user to user so it shouldn't be in source control.

If you're using a database stored in the App_Data folder, be sure to ignore that as well (the database file, not the App_Data folder).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I exclude the bin and obj folders of every project from source control. I can't remember needing to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

do you use ankhsvn?

i think ankhsvn automatically exclueds directories which are not needed in subversion

cheers